Prove that the set is a field but not algebraically closed
Consider the set $$F=\{f=\sum_{i \in \Bbb Z_{\geq \alpha}} a_{i} t^{i}: a_{i} \in K, \alpha \in \Bbb Z \}$$
with $K$ a field.
First of all, i want to prove that $F$ is a field.
The sum is associative since $f_1+(f_2+f_3)=\sum a_i t^i+\left(\sum b_i t^i + \sum c_i t^i \right) = \sum ((a_i+b_i)+c_i) t^i=(f_1+f_2)+f_3$
This is because the coefficients of the polynomials belong to a field, and from here the commutativity, the inverse and the identity for the sum are also deduced, so $(F, +)$ is an abelian group. The commutativity for the product and the associativity can be seen by doing some calculations, which I will not make explicit here.
Now, how do we write the multiplicative inverse and the identity for the product, if $f=\sum_{i \in \Bbb Z_{\geq \alpha}} a_i t^i$, we can take $f^{-1}=\sum_{-i \in \Bbb Z_{\geq \alpha}} (a_i)^{-1}t^{-i}$? In order to ensure that $f \cdot f^{-1}=1$ of course, it depends on who our identity is, since it must be a polynomial such that
$$\sum_{i} \left(\sum_{j} a_j b_{i-j} \right) t^{i}=\sum_{i} a_{i}t^i$$
This is my first obstacle, finding the inverse and the multiplicative identity, since distributivity
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{i} \left(\sum_{j}a_i (b_{i-j} + c_{i-j}) \right)t^i &= \sum_{i} \sum_{j} \left(a_j (b_{i-j} + c_{i-j}) \right) t^i \\
&= \sum_{i} \sum_{j} \left(a_i b_{i-j} + a_i c_{i-j} \right) t^i \\
&= \sum_{i} \sum_{j} (a_i b_{i-j}) t^i + \sum_{i} \sum_{j} (a_i c_{i-j}) t^i \\
\end{aligned}
Except because I don't know how to express the inverse and the identity, we would have to say that it is indeed a field.
Now, to verify that it is not algebraically closed we should express a polynomial of the set that does not have roots in it, I was thinking that a possible candidate could be something of the form
$$p(x)=t^{\frac{4}{5}}$$
In general, any element of the set $$F_1=\{f=\sum_{i \in \Bbb Z_{\geq \alpha}} a_{i} t^{ \frac{i}{k}}: a_{i} \in K, \alpha \in \Bbb Z, k \in \Bbb N \}$$
But I'm not entirely sure if that's the case. Any help for my questions? any suggestion is useful

You need to get much clearer on how the multiplication works. The multiplicative identity is $1$. Now, can you find the inverse of, say, $1 - t$? How about $1 - 2t$?

I should be able to find a polynomial such that $(1-t)(\sum a_i t^i)=\sum a_i t^i-\sum a_i t^{i+1}=1$ But I don't see it at all clear, can you help me a little bit with this? I don't quite understand how such an element should be.

It's not a polynomial, this is the field of Laurent series. Write down what that identity implies about each coefficient $a_i$ slowly, one at a time; collect like terms; what do you get?
